# if string1 or string1 in string3, replace for string4

Tags: python, string, replace

**Set-up**

I need to check a name for the occurrence of either one of two different strings. If either one of the 2 strings is found in the name, I need to replace the string with a 4th string.

---

**Code**

I could do the following,

```
if 'Brązowy' in product_name:
    product_name = product_name.replace('Brązowy','Bruin') 
elif 'Brązowa' in product_name:
    product_name = product_name.replace('Brązowa','Bruin')
```

which works fine.

Or I could do it a bit shorter,

```
if any(x in product_name for x in ['Brązowy','Brązowa']):        
    product_name = product_name.replace('Brązowy','Bruin').replace('Brązowa','Bruin')
```

which also works fine.

---

**Question**

But I was wondering if I could do something like this,

```
if any(x in product_name for x in ['Brązowy','Brązowa']):        
    product_name = product_name.replace(('Brązowy','Brązowa'),'Bruin')
```

Anybody a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would make a function instead.

```
def fix_pname(pname, search, replace):
    for item in search:
        if item in pname:
            return pname.replace(item, replace)
    return pname



product_name = fix_pname(product_name, ['Brązowy','Brązowa'], 'Bruin')
```

Answer (score 1):

you can do this:

```
import re
if any(x in product_name for x in ['Brązowy','Brązowa']):        
    product_name = re.sub(('Brązowy|Brązowa'),'Bruin',product_name)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use regex on the `re` module and have something like:

```py
import re

product_name = "Brązowy na nan nanan Brązowa"

check_strs = ['Brązowy','Brązowa']
if any(x in product_name for x in check_strs):
    product_name = re.sub("|".join(check_strs), "Bruin", product_name)

print(product_name) # > Bruin na nan nanan Bruin
```